# converting an abstract class with base class into interface c#

Tags: c#

I have a abstract class like the following,

```
public abstract class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity, IYouTubePlayerOnInitializedListener
{
    private static int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    public void OnInitializationFailure(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason)
    {
        if (errorReason.IsUserRecoverableError)
        {
            errorReason.GetErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            String errorMessage = String.Format(GetString(Resource.String.error_player), errorReason.ToString());
            Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnInitializationSuccess(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, IYouTubePlayer player, bool wasRestored)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST)
            GetYouTubePlayerProvider().Initialize(KeyKeeper.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    protected abstract IYouTubePlayerProvider GetYouTubePlayerProvider();

}
```

I want to convert into an Interface so that I can do the following,

```
public class foo : INewInterface 
{
//implement all the methods in the above abstract class
}
```

This challenges my OOP understanding, I coudn't figure out a solution for this, I concluded myself that it is not possible, but thought of posting it here to confirm it or to find possible solutions if any.

Comment: If you say it not possible what is your arguments?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to change it to an interface? You can do the exact same thing as it currently exists.

Comment: You cannot force a class implementing an interface to have to inherit from an abstract class. But you shouldn't need to. The abstract class should already implement an interface and be used through that, never "directly". And so you can easily let your new interface inherit from that interface (and possibly a couple of other interfaces). Now every class implementing the new interface is free to implement it, however it wants. Including but not limited to inheriting from the abstract base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information that you've given us, this is all you can do:

```
public interface INewInterface
{
    void OnInitializationFailure(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason);
    void OnInitializationSuccess(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, IYouTubePlayer player, bool wasRestored);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this one.